# Identify and copy values from one row to multiple rows within a group

Tags: r

I am working in RStudio and I have a data frame similar to this:

```
myDF <- data.frame(ID =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                   Address = c('Smith St.','Robin St.','Apple St.', 
                   'Robin St.', 'Smith St.', 'Purple St.','Robin St.', 
                   'Smith St.', 'Big St.', 'Small St.'),
                   Var1 = c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,NA,NA,FALSE,NA,NA,FALSE,FALSE),
                   Var2 = c(1,1,2,NA,NA,4,NA,NA,8,9))
```

For each row with the same Address I need Var1 and Var2 to be the same (i.e., there should be no NA values). Thus, I need some way to copy the actual values for Var1 and Var2 (i.e. not NA values) where they are given for each Address to rows with the same address where Var1 and Var2 are listed as NA. For example, the final data frame should look like this:

```
    myDF <- data.frame(ID =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                   Address = c('Smith St.','Robin St.','Apple St.', 
                   'Robin St.', 'Smith St.', 'Purple St.','Robin St.', 
                   'Smith St.', 'Big St.', 'Small St.'),
                   Var1 = c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,
                          FALSE),
                   Var2 = c(1,1,2,1,1,4,1,1,8,9))
```

My actual data frame has over 14,000 rows and 129 variables. I'm new to R. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

#### Your data

```
myDF <- data.frame(ID =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                   Address = c('Smith St.','Robin St.','Apple St.', 
                               'Robin St.', 'Smith St.', 'Purple St.','Robin St.', 
                               'Smith St.', 'Big St.', 'Small St.'),
                   Var1 = c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,NA,NA,FALSE,NA,NA,FALSE,FALSE),
                   Var2 = c(1,1,2,NA,NA,4,NA,NA,8,9))
```

#### Your expected output

```
myDF_expected <- 
  data.frame(ID =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
           Address = c('Smith St.','Robin St.','Apple St.', 
                       'Robin St.', 'Smith St.', 'Purple St.','Robin St.', 
                       'Smith St.', 'Big St.', 'Small St.'),
           Var1 = c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,
                    FALSE),
           Var2 = c(1,1,2,1,1,4,1,1,8,9))
```

#### Libraries used

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
```

#### Solution

```
my_df_final <-
  myDF %>% 
  group_by(Address) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Var1)) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(na.locf), matches("Var")) %>%
  ungroup %>% 
  arrange(ID) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

my_df_final

   ID    Address  Var1 Var2
1   1  Smith St.  TRUE    1
2   2  Robin St.  TRUE    1
3   3  Apple St. FALSE    2
4   4  Robin St.  TRUE    1
5   5  Smith St.  TRUE    1
6   6 Purple St. FALSE    4
7   7  Robin St.  TRUE    1
8   8  Smith St.  TRUE    1
9   9    Big St. FALSE    8
10 10  Small St. FALSE    9

identical(my_df_final, myDF_expected)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Unfortunately, I'm getting this error message when I try to run this code with my actual data: "Error: incompatible size (%d), expecting %d (the group size) or 1"

Comment: Hi, if the solution does not work on your dataset, than the dataset that you provided is not representative. Please provide one, and I will try to find a new solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(myDF["Address"], myDF[!is.na(myDF$Var1) & !is.na(myDF$Var2),], by = "Address") %>% mutate(ID = row_number()) %>% select(ID, Address, Var1, Var2)
   ID    Address  Var1 Var2
1   1  Smith St.  TRUE    1
2   2  Robin St.  TRUE    1
3   3  Apple St. FALSE    2
4   4  Robin St.  TRUE    1
5   5  Smith St.  TRUE    1
6   6 Purple St. FALSE    4
7   7  Robin St.  TRUE    1
8   8  Smith St.  TRUE    1
9   9    Big St. FALSE    8
10 10  Small St. FALSE    9
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Unfortunately, I'm getting this error message when I try to run this code with my actual data: "Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions." Any idea why or how to remedy?

Comment: You can actually drop the `%>% select(ID, Address, Var1, Var2)` part but then the order of the columns will be a bit different from your desired result.